# ArchUnit packages usage with exceptions for subpackages

Tags: java, archunit

I got seemingly trivial use-case, and still I cannot figure it out. Let's take a look at the package structure.

```
-- CommonPackage
-- Package1
---- DAOs
---- Common
---- Service
-- Package2
---- subpackage1
---- subpackage2
```

What I want to achieve is to create a rule, in which all the classes in the **Package2**, cannot use any of the classes from **Package1** EXCEPT the **common** one. So far I've came with something like this:

```
noClasses()
    .that()
    .resideInAPackage("package2..")            
    .should()
    .resideInAnyPackage("package1..")
    // and how write eg. except("package1.common")
    .check(classes);
```

But I cannot figure out how to exlude **package1.common** from this equasion. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you forgot to include a `.dependOnClassesThat()` in your question.
(Classes in `package2` just don't reside in `package1`... )

If your constraints cannot be expressed by [the fluent API](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#dependOnClassesThat()), consider using more powerful APIs [based on arbitrary `ArchCondition`s](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/GivenClassesConjunction.html#should(com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchCondition)) or [`DescribedPredicate`s](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#dependOnClassesThat(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)).
For constraints expressed as a method call within the fluent API, you can usually find an equivalent predefined `DescribedPredicate` with the same name, e.g. `dependOnClassesThat().resideInAPackage(pkg)` ≡ `dependOnClassesThat(resideInAPackage(pkg))`. Your IDE should help you to find [the right static import](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.Predicates.html#resideInAPackage(java.lang.String)). From there, it's often easy to compose more complex constraints without even having to implement custom `ArchCondition`s or `DescribedPredicate`s.

In your case, I guess you're looking for something like this:

```java
noClasses()
    .that().resideInAPackage("package2..")
    .should().dependOnClassesThat(
        resideInAnyPackage("package1..").and(
            not(resideInAnyPackage("package1.common.."))
        )
    )
```